# Using jQuery to find an attribute, then only do the function based on the attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, attr

ok so i get how to use an attribute, now what i want to do, is for jQuery to find the attribute im using and use it to only open one comment box at a time

html:

```
<div class="commentopen" id="1">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="1"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
<div class="commentopen" id="2">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="2"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
<div class="commentopen" id="3">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="3"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
```

i have the class `.comment display: none;`

jquery:

```
$('.commentopen').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".comment" + id).slideDown(180, function() {
         $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
    });
});
```

i could really use some help here on why its not working. been working on this for days!

Comment: IDs should be [unique within an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). You should rethink your approach.

Comment: Do you have a document.ready() around this code in production? Also, like the few before me, watch out for the ID, maybe use a data-id on your comments instead...

Comment: im using mysql to fetch the comment id's of the different posts.

Comment: I would restructure your ID attribute and make it unique then use a different attribute to determine the kind of action you want. You can use a standard attr such as "rel" or come up with non-standard like "action" or as jcreamer898 have mentioned. BTW--you don't really need to know the action, if you are only opening the next div comment. $('.commentopen').click(function(){ $(this).next('.comment').slideDown(); }); //even .next('div') should work.

Answer (score 3):

You have duplicates in your IDs (e.g. there are two elements with the ID 1), resolve that by adding a prefix:

```
<div class="comment" id="comment1">...
```

Then just go with this:

```
$('#comment' + id).slideDown(...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should never have multiple elements with the same **id**. An **id** should always be unique.

The following will work:

```
<div class="commentopen" id="1">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="c1"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
<div class="commentopen" id="2">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="c2"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
<div class="commentopen" id="3">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="c3"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
```

and:

```
$('.commentopen').click(function() {
    var comment = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#c" + id).slideDown(180, function() {
         $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
    });
});
```

**Update:** I fixed the mistakes mentioned below.

Comment: `$('.c' + id)` would resolve to `$('.cco1')` - how is that supposed to work out?

Comment: wouldnt this output ".cco1" for example. i click the first one, having an id of co1, then it goes to the slide down function ".c" + co1

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the statement is valid, just didnt work in my case, hopefully it works in someone elses!

Answer (score 1):

One problem with your HTML is you are repeating the id of the tags. The ID should be unique over the HTML page. Repeating the same ID to cause some javascript errors.

```
<div class="commentopen" id="1">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="comment_1"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
<div class="commentopen" id="comment_2">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="comment_2"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
<div class="commentopen" id="comment_3">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="comment_3"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
```

and your javascript should be like this

```
$('.commentopen').click(function() {
    var comment = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#comment_" + id).slideDown(180, function() {
         $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".comment" + id).slideDown(180, function() {
```

That id is going to be straight text and thus wont work as a selector, try this:

```
$(".comment #" + id).slideDown(180, function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

look at attribute selectors

change this

```
$(".comment" + id).slideDown(180, function() {
     $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
});
```

to

```
$(".comment[id=" + id+"]").slideDown(180, function() {
     $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
});
```

Comment: i tried all of the other answers, this is the only one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.commentopen').click(function() {
    var comment = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.comment[id="' + id + '"]').slideDown(180, function() {
         $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with what you are doing. First of all, the `id` attribute must be unique on the page, so it can't be shared between 2 divs (e.g. comment and commentopen). Instead, you could have one id based on another, like `id="comment1"` and id="1"`. Then your page would look like this:

```
<div class="commentopen" id="1">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="comment1"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
<div class="commentopen" id="2">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="comment2"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
<div class="commentopen" id="3">Comment</div>
<div class="comment" id="comment3"><textarea>write a comment...</textarea></div>
```

and your jQuery code would look like this:

```
$('.commentopen').click(function() {
 var comment = $(this).attr('id');
 $("#comment" + id).slideDown(180, function() {
      $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that having the same id's on the divs for the click and the textarea's are causing the problem.

have a look at the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpirate/tn4u9/2/)

should solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be:

> ```
> $(".comment#" + id).slideDown(180, function() {
>      $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
> });
> ```

Note the '#' after .comment in the selector. Hope this helps.

Comment: Er - why did you vote this answer down? - it's correct. If you hover over the down arrow below the score you will see that you vote down when an answer 'is not useful'. Do you always kick in the teeth people who are trying to help you?

Comment: Especially when you didn't even state HOW your code wasn't working!

Comment: i have no idea who voted this down, it wasnt me.. thank you for your responce though!

Comment: The OP doesn't have enough reputation to vote down, so someone else did it. Also please don't use flags to complain about downvotes.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the ID, you won't need to use the .comment class anymore in your query

```
$('.commentopen').click(function() {
    var commentId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#"+ commentId).slideDown(180, function() {
         $('#container').isotope('reLayout');
    });
});
```

Comment: this would only be useful if .commentopen was the div i was trying to open. thank you for the responce though

Comment: 'Thank you for the response though'? - yeah - don't expect any more 'responses' if you're voting people down when you don't even seem to know what you're doing.

Comment: dude, im sorry, i didnt vote anyone down! this happened in another answer as well. sorry for the mix-up, i dont even have enough rep to vote so

Comment: Sorry about that DJ_Plus - just assumed it was you - shouldn't have done that.